# Is it possible to substitute project dependency with another project dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to replace all occurence of

```
project compile (':util')
```

in my sub-projects with something like

```
project compile (':standardLib:util')
```

I've tried to do something like

```
subprojects {
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
          substitute project(':util') with project(':standardLib:util')
        }
      }
  }
}
```

But it does not seem to be working as expected. Am i missing something or is it even possible to do that ??

Comment: No gradle wiz here, but if I'd take that literally and would want to change  all occurences of `project compile (':util')` in all build.gradle files into `project compile (':standardLib:util')` I'd simply use `find` and `sed` like so, `find . -name "build.gradle" -exec sed -i "s/project compile (':util')/project compile (':standardLib:util')/g" {} \;`  That will require a unix like environment of course.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing a find-and-replace on your gradle files?

Comment: Are you trying to replace library name or version? Little unclear to me.